# How do i dynamically require module, instantiate object and call function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Building a node app where I'm consistently requiring and doing things with several different bitcoin exchange modules that I've built.  Sometimes I want to add or remove an exchange and it's painful to go through the code to add and remove all the hard-coded references to the exchanges.

Is there a way to do something like this?  Sorry if this is an obvious question - I'm relatively new to node and a (programming) weekend warrior generally.  Thanks in advance for your input.

```
//config.js    
var config = {}
config.exchanges = ['bitfinex', 'bitstamp', 'btce'];
module.exports = config;

//app.js
var config = require('./config');
var _= require('underscore');

_.each(config.exchanges, function(exchange){

    //obviously not correct, but how would I accomplish something like this?

    var Exchange = require('./api/exchange');
    var exchange = new Exchange();
    exchange.do_stuff();

});
```

Comment: You don't need to `require` the module again and again, make `Exchange` a global variable (like `config` and `_`). And you should pass the `exchange` string (that contains `'bitfinex'` etc) to the `Exchange` constructor, and maybe not overwrite the `exchange` string with the `Exchange` instance (but use a different variable name)

Answer (score 0):

This i the piece of code that load models, controllers and api files without a reference:

```
  # Bootstrap models
  models_path = __dirname + "/models"
  fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach (file) ->
    require models_path + "/" + file  if ~file.indexOf(".js")

  # Bootstrap controllers
  controllers_path = __dirname + "/controllers"
  fs.readdirSync(controllers_path).forEach (file) ->

    app.controllers[file.slice(0, -3)] = require(controllers_path + "/" + file)  if ~file.indexOf(".js")
    return

  # Bootstrap api
  api_path = __dirname + "/api"
  fs.readdirSync(api_path).forEach (file) ->

    app.api[file.slice(0, -3)] = require(api_path + "/" + file)  if ~file.indexOf(".js")
    return
```

Hope it helps